# Difference between .state('init.home') and .state('/home')

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs. can you explain me difference between
.state('init.home') and .state('/home')

Thanks Inadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) and in that case, here's the difference:

.state('init.home') would be something you can reference within an HTML template using `<a ui-sref="init.home">Click me</a>` and it will transition the user to that state.

That state would look something like this:

```
.state('init.home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "views/home.html",
  controller: "HomeController"
})
```

Generally you would also have .state('init') as the parent, something like:

```
.state('init', {
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
    authenticated: ['$auth', function($auth) {
      if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        $state.go('login');
      }
  }
})
```

That would ensure any transition to a child state under 'init' would have access to 'authenticated' for ensuring the user was logged in, as an example.

.state('/home') isn't actually valid. You would instead define the state and use the 'url' parameter to specify the location:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home'
}
```

This page is probably a good resource to review: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 0):

States can be nested within each other. There are several ways of nesting states:

Using 'dot notation'. For example .state('contacts.list', {})...

please read this [article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) for more details.